# Is there a way to make all layers visible in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shortcuts

Is there a way to make all layers visible in Photoshop? Is there a quick way to do this, for example, short key or script?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a huge number of layers:

The fastest way is to click+drag over all the layer eyeballs, this works in CS5 at least. Note that visibility changes are not undo-able, i.e. they don't show up in history

A better suggestion for the future; get used to organizing layers into groups, then you will have far less 'points' to turn on/off layers.

There are also some [cool layer shortcuts here](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/layer-shortcuts/)

Answer (score 13):

Select all layers by Pressing Ctrl + Alt + A, and then with the layers selected go to Layer>Hide layers and then Layer>Show layers.  Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me in 2023!

Answer (score 12):

right click the eyeball of any layer.  there is a show/hide all that is the same as alt clicking an eyeball. select it.  if it hides all layers, then repeat.  it will show them all.  if you would like a hot key, use the action palate to automate this sequence of actions.

Answer (score 8):

Create one blank layer to the top of the all layers and point your mouse to this new created layer eyeball and press the Alt Button on/off .

new created layer will off while all the layers are off and v/versa.

Answer (score 8):

**Show/Hide all layers:**

You can use the "show all/hide all layers" by right clicking on the eyeball on any layer and selecting the "show/hide" option. It will make all the layers visible.

[image: show/hide all layers in Adobe Photoshop]

You can also use the other shortcut mentioned above (*Command + Alt + A*) and then use the shortcut *Command + ,*

**Show/Hide all layers but one:**

If you want to hide all the other layers but not a specific one, you can hold the *ALT key* and click on the eyeball on the selected layer. It will show/hide all the active layers but the one you selected.

It will not make the layers that were not visible.... visible, though!

**Show/Hide one layer**

Simply click *Command + ,* (it does the same as clicking the eyeball on one layer).

You can change that shortcut in the menu Edit > Keyboard Shortcut > Layers

Comment: This also worked for me in 2023! Thank you for illustration graphic

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl + Alt + A` to select all layers

`Ctrl + ,` to hide or unhide selected layers

Comment: Perhaps this solution was not available in 2016, however this is the first *true* keyboard shortcut solution. Works perfectly in Windows 10!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question answered a long time ago.

but for those who read all answers :-D

You can select All Layers by this shortcut <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> [as Rokas Says] and then press <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> and toggle all layer to Hide Or Unhide.

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

All above answer plus regards history.

Yes you can also make layer show/hide process into history so that after showing all layers, revert back to previous. Do the following.

- Go to **Window > History** to show history panel if it is not already visible.
- Click on small triangle on top right of the history panel and click on **History Options** to show additional options for history panel.
- From the options that popup, mark last option **Make Layer Visibility Changes Undoable** checked.

and that's it. So now after showing/hiding all layers, we can always go back to history of layer's visibility.

[image]

[image]